# Dirac/Weyl/Majorana Basis and their Importance

Tags: representation-theory, dirac-equation, majorana-fermions, clifford-algebra

I have just begun studying Dirac equations and was confused by the physical significance of Dirac Basis. In principle, we can have as many representations of Clifford Algebra as we wish by conducting unitary transformations. In that sense, why Dirac/Weyl/Majorana basis are more important physically? Are these representations related to Dirac/Weyl/Majorana fermions?